# How does $\sigma’(x)$ simplify to $\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{aligned}
\sigma^{\prime}(x) &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \\
&=\frac{e^{-x}}{\left(1+e^{-x}\right)^{2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \cdot \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \\
&=\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))
\end{aligned}

I do not understand what is the last step in this derivative. How can you factor out the last term?

\begin{aligned}
\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} = \frac{(1+e^{-x})-1}{1+e^{-x}} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} = 1- \sigma(x)$$